# Calculating accuracy for graph clusterting algorithms

Tags: clustering, graph-theory

I am trying to cluster a graph based on similarity between nodes. To calculate accuracy of my clusters based on expert (human) classification I initially thought to use techniques like Purity or Confusion Matrix. Is there any specific technique for graph clusters or will the above mentioned techniques work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spectral clustering (see section 2 in http://www.kyb.mpg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/publications/attachments/Luxburg07_tutorial_4488%5b0%5d.pdf) seems to be what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a classification metric.

Use a cluster evaluation metric such as the adjusted Rand index (ARI) and normalized mutual information (NMI). See the Wikipedia article on clustering.